Jest Unit tests are failing
Getting below error while running unit tests for react app. I am using jest to run it.
I didn't have the file mentioned in below error in my code base.
I searched many places but didn't found solution. Can anyone help me with this?
`
Test suite failed to run
Cannot find module 'node:stream' from 'index.js'

However, Jest was able to find:
    './Utils.js'
    './Utils.js.map'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

However, Jest was able to find:
    './utils.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

However, Jest was able to find:
    './createSerializer.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/parse5-parser-stream/dist/cjs/index.js:4:23)

`
I searched in many forums and tries some options but didn't worked.

Please share a snippet of your test suite code.

This issue is coming for all test suits irrespective of what it has.

I ran into this issue the other day too.  Turned out to be a dependency of Enzyme that was causing the issue.  I had to pin "cheerio" to version "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.12".  The latest version "1.0.0-rc.3" was installing parse5-parser-stream which is causing the node:stream error.  Hope this helps!

It is so annoying jest wasn't providing enough logs to find what was going wrong. thanks, your answer saved my day.

This saved my day, thank you!
How did you find the root cause?

I started looking at dependencies of Enzyme and Jest.  Then dug through some of the code in node_modules of those dependencies.  Finally found 'node:stream' in parse5-parser-stream.  I looked back in the history of our application and noticed that was never installed before and I saw the cheerio version was different as well.  So, I set the version back and re-installed everything and the parse5-parser-stream was no longer a dependency.  Glad it helped you!

Glad I found this!!! Thank you so much!

worked like a charm. thanks.

npm install cheerio@1.0.0-rc.12

I ran into the same issue, as @jlogue mentioned, but I had it as a transitive dependency - Added it as a top-level dependency, with version "1.0.0-rc.12" and it worked like a charm.
Great catch!
